# Error 1093. You can't specify target table 'ps_order_history' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1093

I have been searching, but I still don't understand why it's wrong. I checked the subqueries, and they're returning just 1 row.

```
UPDATE ps_order_history

SET id_order_state = 18

WHERE id_order = 
(
    SELECT max(p.id_order)
    FROM ps_orders p
    INNER JOIN ps_order_detail d ON d.id_order = p.id_order
    INNER JOIN ps_order_history oh ON oh.id_order = p.id_order
    WHERE d.product_name = "Academia Mastermaq" 

    AND p.id_customer = 
    (
        SELECT id_customer
        FROM ps_customer
        WHERE firstname = "Cristiano"
        AND lastname = "Ferreira dos Santos"
        LIMIT 1
    )
)

Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'ps_order_history' 
for update in FROM clause
```

Thanks!

Comment: you cannot update a table you're selecting from. e.g. your update is working on `ps_order_history`, and you're selecting from `ps_order_history` as one of the joined fields in your WHERE subselect.

Answer (score 0):

Now I know I can't join my update table in a subquery. Thanks to [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b)!

```
UPDATE ps_order_history h
INNER JOIN ps_order_detail d ON d.id_order = h.id_order

SET h.id_order_state = 15

WHERE d.product_name = "Academia Mastermaq" 
AND h.id_order = 
(
    SELECT max(p.id_order)
    FROM ps_orders p
    /*INNER JOIN ps_order_detail d ON d.id_order = p.id_order
    INNER JOIN ps_order_history oh ON oh.id_order = p.id_order*/


    WHERE p.id_customer = 
    (
        SELECT id_customer
        FROM ps_customer
        WHERE firstname = "Cristiano"
        AND lastname = "Ferreira dos Santos"
        LIMIT 1
    )
)
```